# PHP Explode Function

Tags: php

Im just wondering if there a way to write this code in just one line.

```
$exp = explode(" ", $text);
$cut = $exp[0];
```

So without having to assign variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only ever want the first part, then avoid the array workaround with [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok):

```
$cut = strtok($text, " ");
```

It cuts out something from the string until the first delimiter (space in your case).

Comment: This is a very good answer, and it works perfectly unless the first character is `" "`. The result of OP's question would be an empty string and the result of your answer would be the string from char at pos 1 to the next space. +1 anyway.

Comment: @richard86: Interesting. I never realized it actually skips to the first non-delimiter. Would usually apply `trim()` to get that exact behaviour. But that's a significant difference to explode then, if you might need/expect an empty string part too.

Answer (score 4):

```
$cut = preg_replace('/ [\s\S]*$/', '', $text);
```

http://codepad.org/yujJRnYS

Answer (score 3):

```
$var = reset(explode(" ", $text));
```

Comment: but you would end up with a `$var` that has the first element (like the questions `$cut`, but with nothing that would have the complete array, like `$exp`

Comment: this will give an error too: `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: @Nanne. That's the question of OP.

Comment: Hmm, thought I left another comment? anyway @ question: you are right :D I ignored that line because without assigning anything this would be rather pointless, but interpreting it as "without assiging anything extra" it's quite valid :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$cut = substr ( $text, 0, strpos ( $text, ' ' ) );
```

OR

```
$cut = substr ( trim ( $text ), 0, strpos ( trim ( $text ), ' ' ) );
```